# How to debug c# COM exposed component used by local IIS application

Tags: c#, iis, asp-classic, com, visual-studio-debugging

I am having some issues figuring out how to setup my developement enviroment to hit breakpoints in a COM exposed c# class library project (framework v4.6.1) i've added to an already existing asp classic solution hosted on an local IIS v10.0.1. For developing and debugging i am using Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.5

COM exposed component is working just fine and is consumed by asp via late binding. Debugging classic asp also work fine when attached to w3wp process. But when attaching to w3wp process breakpoints in class library turns white saying "no symbols loaded for document" even though an PDB file is located in class library bin/debug folder.

For testing if breakpoints could be hit with other type of startup projects, i've added a simple console project to same solution. This also seems to work fine. Its only when using w3wp process the problem occours.

What i have tried so far:

- Rebuilding class library project
- Disabling Visual Studio debugging property "Just My Code"
- Enabling class library build property "Register for COM interop"
- Restarted pc

Been browsing the web for hours to find a solution to this issue, but can t seem to find anything indicating this should be a problem. Leading me to think i missed something obvious.

Hope someone can shed some light on how this should be solved.

Comment: When you build the DLL is it using the `Debug` configuration or `Release`?

Comment: Related: [.NET - How to debug a DLL?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2622250)

Comment: @Lankymart I am building it with debug configuration. I just had a look at the correct answer you linked to, and the three step guide is exactly how i am doing it, and would expect it to work.